# Маскировка изображения с помощью CSS

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg, mask

Я сделал такой дизайн:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как с помощью CSS  фигурно обрезать нижний край фона?

Я пробовал такой код:

```css
.img-poster {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  -webkit-mask-image: url(https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/GYiCod1.png), url(https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/GYiCQsM.png);
  -webkit-mask-position: bottom center, center center;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
}

.add {
  -webkit-mask-composite: add;
}
```

```html
<section class="section poster-container">
  <img src="https://imagejournal.org/wp-content/uploads/bb-plugin/cache/23466317216_b99485ba14_o-panorama.jpg" alt="" class="img-poster add img-responsive">
</section>
```

Изображение для маски, которое я использовал:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fg2k5.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmylJ.png

Можете ли вы сказать мне, что не так в моем коде?
Я знаю, что могу просто импортировать в PNG, но я пытался использовать CSS

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/47829139/7394871

Answer (score 3):

> [Перевод ответа @Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47829344/7394871) на вопрос EnSO: [masking image with
>   CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47829139/7394871)

Вам нужно  использовать только одно изображение, которое является нижней частью вашей маски, а затем использовать простой градиент для другой части. Вам  не нужна `mask-composite` 
Просто отрегулируйте `size/position`, чтобы обе маски не перекрывались:

```css
.img-poster {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  -webkit-mask:  
     linear-gradient(#fff,#fff)              top,
     url(https://i.ibb.co/5WvbqgG/zmylJ.png) bottom;
  -webkit-mask-size:
     100% calc(100% - 30px),
     auto 30px;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: repeat-x;
  mask:  
     linear-gradient(#fff,#fff)              top,
     url(https://i.ibb.co/5WvbqgG/zmylJ.png) bottom;
  mask-size:
     100% calc(100% - 30px),
     auto 30px;
  mask-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<section class="section poster-container">
  <img src="https://imagejournal.org/wp-content/uploads/bb-plugin/cache/23466317216_b99485ba14_o-panorama.jpg" alt="" class="img-poster add img-responsive">
</section>
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47829344/7394871): @Temani Afif

Comment: И скажем так, если я зохочу изменить маску то придётся лепить в фотошопе, а вектор в полне можно руками исправить или нарисовать

Answer (score 2):

### Решение SVG + filter

Эффект достигается использованием одного и того же изображения 2 раза.

К нижнему изображению применены фильтры `feTurbulence` и `feDisplacementMap`. Изменяя их атрибуты  `baseFrequency`,  `numOctaves="2"`, `seed="1"`, `scale="75"` придаем краям зубчатую форму.  За счет этого изображение увеличивается в ширину и высоту.

Накладываем сверху точно такое же изображение, но меньшего размера. По краям обрезаем маской, чтобы оставить зубчатую форму только снизу, как в образце вопроса.

```css
.container {
 width:100vw;
 height:100vh;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   viewBox="0 0 1800 900" >
 <defs> 
   <mask id="msk1"> 
        <rect x="100%" y="100%"  fill="white" /> 
      <rect x="1700" y="0" width="50" height="900" fill="white" />
   </mask>
     <filter id="displacementFilter">
     <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency="0.01 0.01"
        numOctaves="2" result="turbulence" seed="1"/>
    <feDisplacementMap in2="turbulence" in="SourceGraphic"
        scale="75" xChannelSelector="R" xChannelSelector="G" yChannelSelector="B"/>
    </filter>    
 </defs> 
        
       <!-- Изображение обработано фильтром и пэтому увеличились габаритные размеры за счет высоты зубцов -->
   <image   filter="url(#displacementFilter)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/paWbQ.jpg" width="1700" height="850" />
    <rect mask="url(#msk1)" x="1700" y="0" width="50" height="900" fill="white" /> 
    <!-- Точно такое же исходное изображение, но без обработки  -->
  <image x="0"  xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/paWbQ.jpg" width="1700" height="850" />
</svg> 
</div>
```

*Другое изображение*

```css
.container {
 width:90vw;
 height:90vh;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   viewBox="0 0 1800 900" >
 <defs> 
   <mask id="msk1"> 
        <rect x="100%" y="100%"  fill="white" /> 
      <rect x="1700" y="0" width="50" height="900" fill="white" />
   </mask>
     <filter id="displacementFilter">
     <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency="0.01 0.01"
        numOctaves="2" result="turbulence" seed="1"/>
    <feDisplacementMap in2="turbulence" in="SourceGraphic"
        scale="75" xChannelSelector="R" xChannelSelector="G" yChannelSelector="B"/>
    </filter>    
 </defs> 
        
       <!-- Изображение обработано фильтром и пэтому увеличились габаритные размеры за счет высоты зубцов -->
   <image   filter="url(#displacementFilter)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaYSe.jpg" width="1700" height="850" />
    <rect mask="url(#msk1)" x="1700" y="0" width="50" height="900" fill="white" /> 
    <!-- Точно такое же исходное изображение, но без обработки  -->
  <image x="0"  xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaYSe.jpg" width="1700" height="850" />
</svg> 
</div>
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60514148/7394871): @Alexandr_TT